# How to display one row of data multiple times

Tags: ssms, reportbuilder3.0

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2014 and have one row of data that I'd like to display multiple times on a report. The data is shown below:

1 ACT 20117843-07 START 2/13/2017  FINISH 2/14/2017
2 ACT 20117843-07 START 2/13/2017  FINISH 2/14/2017

The current report has a group based on the Start date so the information would only appear once on 2/13/2017. However, I've had a request to display the same activity if it isn't scheduled to Finish on the same day as another row on 2/14/2017.

I've never been asked to do this before so I'm not quite sure how to accomplish the request.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Add Adjacent Group to Start Date and FINISH Date in the report